# LLDB debugger step resolution

Tags: c, xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

I've launched LLDB debugger from command line, with target stand-alone C executable, and set the start of `main()` method as breakpoint.

After running the application in the debugger, I saw that it stops on assembly line, rather then C code line. In addition, every time I stepped forward, the step resolution is a single assembly line.

Here's the output of lldb:

```
(lldb) target create "./a.out"
Current executable set to './a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) breakpoint set --name main
Breakpoint 1: where = a.out`main, address = 0x0000000100000e80
(lldb) run
Process 2023 launched: './a.out' (x86_64)
Process 2023 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xfca5, 0x0000000100000e80 a.out`main, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
frame #0: 0x0000000100000e80 a.out`main a.out`main:
->  0x100000e80 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x100000e81 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000e84 <+4>: pushq  %r15
    0x100000e86 <+6>: pushq  %r14
(lldb) n
Process 2023 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xfca5, 0x0000000100000e81 a.out`main + 1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = instruction step over
frame #0: 0x0000000100000e81 a.out`main + 1
a.out`main:
->  0x100000e81 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x100000e84 <+4>: pushq  %r15
    0x100000e86 <+6>: pushq  %r14
    0x100000e88 <+8>: pushq  %r12
(lldb) n
```

Is there any way I can change the step resolution for a single C source line rather then assembly line (like I get when running lldb from Xcode) ?

Comment: Did you compile with `-g` or similar ?

Comment: compiling the code with -g flag seems to have fixed the problem. what does this option represents in clang compiler ?

Comment: In gcc, clang et al `-g` enables debug symbols in the generated code - you usually want this for any debug or profiling builds (and sometimes even release builds too).

Comment: I've converted this to an answer now, for any future visitors to the question...

Comment: Great that, i've just noticed that on the gcc/clang manual. however, i did try to compile with -O flag that should give more debugging information, perhaps do you know what's the difference between -O to -g

Comment: No, `-O` relates to code optimisation. Its relevance to debugging is that you normally want minimum optimisation for debug builds (`-O0`), and a higher optimisation level for release builds (`-O2` or `-O3`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compile with debug symbols enabled (e.g. `-g`) in order for gdb or lldb to be able to step at the source level.

In gcc, clang, *et al* `-g` enables debug symbols in the generated code - you usually want this for any debug or profiling builds (and sometimes even release builds too).